# Is the date function based on the clients or server's clock? (PHP)

Tags: php

Just curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP executes on the server, so the server. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 3):

Web server's, since PHP is a server-side language.

Answer (score 1):

Server. There is no easy way for the server to know client's date and time.

Comment: Uhh, except using a client-side script

Comment: @BlueRaja, yeah I thought browser is sending the time of the request in the headers, but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Its based on the server's clock.